# scrolling a webview inside a Listview won't work in android

Tags: android, listview, webview, adapter

I have an application which shows a multiple webView inside a listView. My problem is when I try to scroll the webView up and down, the webView does not respond to my finger except if I used 3 fingers only. And when it responds it's hardly moving up and down. I figured out that the problem is the listview is banning the webView from scrolling. I have tried using:

```
listView.setEnabled(false);
```

But it didn't work for me. could anyone show me how to solve this problem? 
This is how I added the webView layout inside a listView.

```
ArrayList<DefaultCards> cardsList = new ArrayList<>();
    cardsList.add(new DefaultCards("Hello Google","https://www.google.com", new WebViewClient()));
    CardsAdapter cardsAdapter = new CardsAdapter(this, cardsList);
    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.cards_listview);
    listView.setAdapter(cardsAdapter);
    listView.setEnabled(false);
```

And this is the layout that will show the listView:

```
<ListView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/cards_listview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And finally, this is the layout that will be inserted into a listView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/colorBackground"
android:padding="5dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take this with a grain of salt but you might want to try using a recycler view for your list holder and a nested scroll view for your webview container.

Also, if the content of the webview is large enough to scroll you may need to add the isScrollContainer="true" attribute to your webview's xml.

Again, this is just a wild guess. Hope it helps!

Comment: using nested scroll view worked for me. Thanks, Patty.

Comment: Glad that it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

The listview is intercepting the scrolling. You can prevent this by creating a NestedScrollingWebView that implements NestedScrollingChild, NestedScrollingParent.

There are many code samples if you search for Nested Scrolling Webview.
Use that instead of a regular Webview.